# python intra pc client-server - dbus alternative?

Tags: python, client

I need to estabilish client-server communications on a single pc (no network) and the only option I found so far is to use dbus.

The problem is that python-dbus seems to work bad on wondows so far (my app is cross platform), furthermore I read that python-dbus api continues to change breaking code.

Is there an alternative to this, preferably using the python standard library?

I was considering the use of sockets and loopback 127.0.0.1 but this way I have to use a port risking another app is already using that port.

Answer (score 0):

I think that use a socket is the best way to do that. You can use the port you want.

If you want to reduce the risk of port conflict, just put the port into a config file and load it to the start of the software.

You can also use a parameter when you call your software like (the best solution in my opinion) :

```
./my_soft -p 8584
```

Of course, 8584 is an example. To do that easily, my advice is to use the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) library.

Comment: I'm working with sockets as you adviced, the problem is that my app (giuspen.com/cherrytree) is graphical so the user starts without arguments. Basically the client server communication is needed to control if there's already one instance of app+filepath running and eventually rise it instead of opening a new instance